# How to retrieve the elements of a dropdownlist in jquery and send it with ajax to an MVC Controller in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a select item as follows:

```
<select id="id_category">
    <option> </option>
</select>
```

In run time there is a tree view used to fill up the select menu as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data').jstree({
        "plugins": ["checkbox"]
    });

    $("#data").on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        if (data.selected.length) {
            $("#id_category").empty(); 
            $(data.selected).each(function (idx) {
                var node = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[idx]);
                var s = document.getElementById('id_category');
                s.options[s.options.length] = new Option(node.text, '1');
            });
        }
        else
            $("#id_category").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

and the html for the tree is not important now as it works well.

Now, I want when a user click on a button with HTML as follows:

```
<input id="btn3" type="button" value="Test 3" />
```

an ajax will be run to send all the items in the select to a controller in MVC as follows:

```
$("#btn3").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Products/Test03",
        datatype: "text",
        data: $.map($('#id_category')[0].options, function( elem ) { return (elem.value || elem.text); }),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#testarea').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

and the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Test03(Object str1)
{
    // call with two parameters and return them back
    this.myRetrievedData = str1; 
    return str1.ToString();
}
```

The above did not work with me, when I click on Test3 button nothing happened. 
I am not sure how to pass the retrieved items to the function in the controller. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: You `$.map()` function returns an array, so your method parameter should be `IEnumerable<string> str` (not `Object`). What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below logic must work for you. **`Many thanks to Mr.Stephen Muecke for assistance.`**

```
     $("#btn3").click(function () {

       var optionsData= $.map($('#id_category')[0].options, function(elem) {
                  return (elem.value || elem.text);
               }); // create a variable to hold all the options array.

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Products/Test03",
            datatype: "text",
            data: JSON.stringify(optionsData), //pass this variable to post request as 'options'
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#testarea').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
            }
        });
    });
```

Then you can have your controller as below.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Test03(IEnumerable<string> options ) // change here to this
{
    //your logic goes here        
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown will not work unless you add `traditional: true` (or use `data: JSON.stringify(optionsData),` with `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can I get you a Beer ?

Comment: Still not right - just `JSON.stringify(optionsData),` - using `data: {options : JSON.stringify(optionsData)}` would result in an exception - `Invalid JSON primitive: options.` :)

Comment: You mean the error would be in the Client side itself?? I actually work it this way. Also we need to assign it to `options` so that MVC binds it properly in the ActionResult right?

Comment: No it will not work unless you make the change. Suggest you try the code yourself with a simple array. You will get a `500(Internal Server Error)` and the Response will be as I noted above.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you were right. Thank you so much for correcting me.

Comment: @AymenKareem if this solution helped you resolve your issue then you can mark it as answer as it will be useful for future audience

Comment: You can see a `Check Mark` symbol under the upvote and downvote icons. Just tick that to mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have not added [HttpPost] attribute in your controller function

Comment: There is HttpPost above the controller